# java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@3fb43c24

Tags: java, android, multithreading, monkey

**I test my program using monkey and appeared the following error, but I did not use 'AsyncTask', does anybody can help me solve this problem.**

```
Short Msg: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
Long Msg: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@3fb43c24 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@31e8c38d[Running, pool size = 17, active threads = 17, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 1302]
Build Label: Meizu/meizu_mx5/mx5:5.1/LMY47I/1438146084:user/test-keys
Build Changelist: 1438146084
Build Time: 1438146241000
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@3fb43c24 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@31e8c38d[Running, pool size = 17, active threads = 17, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 1302]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2011)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:793)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1339)
at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:594)
at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.executePendingTask(AsyncTaskLoader.java:235)
at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnCancelled(AsyncTaskLoader.java:248)
at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onCancelled(AsyncTaskLoader.java:103)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:634)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5678)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: Are you using a `CursorLoader`? It extends `AsyncTaskLoader`, which uses `AsyncTask` internally.

Comment: Thank you very much... this issue is really caused by cursorloader....